# Multiple calling javascript from shortcode in one page

Tags: plugins, pages, shortcode

I'm preparing plugin and I have trouble to call (and return) javascript from each (same) shortcode in one wp page/post. Javascript returns values only to last shortcode in page.

PHP code here:

```
add_shortcode( 'ada_chart', 'ada_chart_stranka' ); 
function ada_chart_stranka ($atts) {            
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cid' => '',
    ), $atts );     
    $cislo_chart = $a['cid'];                
    wp_register_script( 'ada_chart_handle', plugins_url().'/ada-chart/js/ada-chart1.js' );
    $ada_sheet_params = array(
        'ada_ch_cislo'      =>  $cislo_chart,
    );  
    wp_localize_script( 'ada_chart_handle', 'ada_ch', $ada_sheet_params );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ada_chart_handle');     
    return 'atribut: '.$cislo_chart;        
}
```

and JS script here:

```
    var cisloChart = ada_ch.ada_ch_cislo;
document.getElementById('chart_div'+cisloChart).innerHTML = 'Cislo: ' + cisloChart;
```

Can anybody hepl me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script should be enqueued and localized only one time per page; so, what you describe is the correct behaviour. I think you are confusing localizing a script with printing inline JavaScript. Also, enqueuing and localizing should be done in `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

You need to think in a different approach.

For example (just a example), you could use dataset API:

First, enqueue the script:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cyb_enqueue_scripts' );
function cyb_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ada_chart_handle', plugins_url().'/ada-chart/js/ada-chart1.js' );
}
```

Second, use the data atribute to include the `cid` value:

```
add_shortcode( 'ada_chart', 'ada_chart_stranka' ); 
function ada_chart_stranka ($atts) {            
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cid' => '',
    ), $atts );     

    $cislo_chart = $a['cid'];                

    return '<div data-cid="' . $cislo_chart . '"></div>';        
}
```

Third, write JavaScript that use dataset API to read the data-cid attribute and perform the desired action:

```
// Get all elements with data-cid attribute
var a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cid]');

// Loop over all selected elements
for (var i in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

    // Get the value of data-cid attribute for current element in the loop
    var cid = a[i].getAttribute('data-cid');

    // Do something with the cid value

}
```

Comment: Technically, there's nothing really limiting you to enqueueing and localizing scripts only within `wp_enqueue_scripts`. If you're outputting on `wp_footer`, calling those anywhere in between is still valid.

Comment: Right, that is why I said "should be" and not "have to be"; but really, in almost every case you want to enqueue in `wp_enqueue_scripts`, specially if the scripts have dependencies, even if you want to output on footer.

Answer (score 0):

Cybmeta,

thanks a lot for your answer. Your idea saved me a lot of sleepless nights )

I tried to use your solution but there was some trouble. The browser has showed empty divs, without signalisation any error in Javascript.

But finally I have combined your and my solution that working very well. Seems that wp_enqueue_scripts is better to use inside the shortcode.

Final solution:

PHP script:

```
    add_shortcode( 'ada_chart', 'ada_chart_stranka' ); 

function ada_chart_stranka ($atts) {            
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cid' => '',
    ), $atts );   

    $cislo_chart = $a['cid'];                
   wp_enqueue_script( 'ada_chart_handle', plugins_url().'/ada-chart/js/ada-chart.js');        
    return 'atribut: '.$cislo_chart.'<br><div id="chart_div'.$cislo_chart.'" data-cid="' . $cislo_chart . '" style="height: 150px; background: #d5d5d5"></div>';       
}
```

Javascript:

```
    var a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cid]');
    for (var i in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

      // Get the value of data-cid attribute for current element in the loop
      var cid = a[i].getAttribute('data-cid');

      'Cislo: ' + cid;

      // Do something with the cid value
      document.getElementById('chart_div'+cid).innerHTML = 'Cislo: ' + cid;
    }
```

Comment: "`wp_enqueue_script()` is better to use inside the shortcode": definitely not. The issue must be some where else, very probably related with the JavaScript code (as I sais in the answer, I write jsut a proof of concept example). I don't know, maybe it needs to wait until DOM is ready before it tries to find elements. But that is a very different issue. Anyway, glad you found a working code.